# (Docker)for app Cannot create container for service app: invalid volume specification:

Tags: python, docker

Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install pip -U
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --default-timeout=1000 -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.douban.com -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

This error occurred when I tried to make an image with docker -compose up:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IicnL.png)

Is there something wrong with my path Settings?

Comment: What's the base image you're using?

Comment: services.app.volumes > `/code` folder/directory doesn't exists in docker container, you should make sure that directory exists and then give absolute path to the directory, like `/var/www/html/code`

Answer (score 0):

The volumes path needs to be the path of the Dockerfile. Seems that inside the Dockerfile, you have the working directory set to `code`, however, all you need to set the volume path to is that of where you have your Dockerfile in local machine stored.

You can simply specify the entire path [/f/HomeWork/GraduateProject/Project/lianjiaweb/] or write `.` in the volume paths.